# How do I get Linq-to-SQL to refresh its local copy of a database record?

Tags: linq-to-sql

Suppose I have an Orders table in my database and a corresponding model class generated by the VS2008 "Linq to SQL Classes" designer. Suppose I also have a stored procedure (`ProcessOrder`) in my database that I use to do some processing on an order record.

If I do the following:

```
var order = dataContext.Orders.Where(o => o.id == orderId).First();

// More code here

dataContext.ProcessOrder(orderId);

order.Status = "PROCESSED";

dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

...then I'll get a concurrency violation if the `ProcessOrder` stored proc has modified the order (which is of course very likely), because L2S will detect that the order record has changed, and will fail to submit the changes to that order.

That's all fairly logical, but what if I *want* to update the order record after calling the stored proc? How do I tell L2S to forget about its cached copy and refresh it from the DB?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do it with the `Refresh` method on your data context, like so:

```
DataContext.Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues,
                    DataContext.Orders);
```

Comment: Perfect. I see that I can also specify a specific order record too, which is exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: But it doesn't update the associated navigation collection property which maps to another table. It is updating only the properties which map to the column of the table to which the current Entity points to. Is there a way out of this?

Answer (score 1):

DataContext.Refresh works but is very slow.

A faster way is to clear the DataContext cache using this method:

```
public static void ClearCache(this DataContext context)
{
    const BindingFlags FLAGS = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
    var method = context.GetType().GetMethod("ClearCache", FLAGS);
    method.Invoke(context, null);
}
```

Then just call ClearCache(dataContext) and it will refresh.

Comment: Hmmm... the fact that method isn't public would give me pause...

Comment: True. I haven't used it much, but so far no issues. Use with caution